# Two versions of same script on server/weird behavior

Tags: ssh, bash, scp

I uploaded a bash script to my vps using scp. Then I changed a line locally, deleted it on the server and uploaded it again to the home directory. Now I'm facing this extremely weird behavior:

If I upload it with scp and then nano it on the server, the old version shows

```
nano setup_virtual_host.sh
```

But if I cat it, the new version shows:

```
cat setup_virtual_host.sh
```

If I run it with

```
sudo ./setup_virtual_host.sh
```

the old version gets executed.

I have no idea what is happening here.

Comment: What os is running in your local machine where you changed one line? If it's a Windows system did you use an editor that understands UNIX/Linux line endings (ie LF rather than CR/LF)?

Comment: It would clarify things if you showed the output of `pwd` before each of the `nano` and `cat` commands; perhaps also with an `ls -l setup_virtual_host.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are editing the same file you're re-uploading via scp? You can use this command to view the full file path of the file. Then, run the same commands with the full path

```
readlink -f setup_virtual_host.sh
```

A full path will be outputted. Use that full path to run the nano, cat and execute the script. You can also check if the file is not located somewhere in your PATH

```
which setup_virtual_host.sh
```